# jinja2: Use a global variable to select latex blocks of text

Tags: python, latex, jinja2

I am trying to use jinja2 and python to generate a latex document. I have a file that use jinja2 and python called `jinja_engine.py`:

```
import jinja2
import os


dict_map = {
    'case1' : [1,2,3],
    'case2' : [1,3],
    'case3' : [3]
}

latex_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
block_start_string = '((*',
block_end_string = '*))',
variable_start_string = '(((',
variable_end_string = ')))',
comment_start_string = '((=',
comment_end_string = '=))',
loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath('.'))
)

template = latex_jinja_env.get_template('template.tex')
template.render(dict_map)
```

I would like to use the `dict_map` dictionary (global variable) to select which text block should be rendered in latex and which should be not. The `template.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.4in}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\sloppy

\begin{document}


((* for i in dict_map['case3'] *))
  ((* if i == 1 *))
  This is the first block  \\[10pt]
  ((* elif i == 2 *))
  This is the second block \\[10pt]
  ((* else *))
  This is the third block \\[10pt]
  ((* endif *))
((* endfor* ))
\end{document}
```

In this case only the `This is the third block` string should be rendered. I am trying to run `python jinja_engine.py` but I am get `dict_map` not defined. How can I pass `dict_map` to the `jinja.Environment` and than use it in my `template.tex`? I am new to jinja2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out several things I could make this work just by replacing in the `jinja_engine.py` file:

```
template.render(dict_map)
```

with

```
template.render(dict_map = dict_map)
```

In this way I can use `dict_map` global variable in the `template.tex` file